# Params not recognised if request sent through iOS client, Curl the same url works as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails

So I do a GET request from an ios app to my server. The response I get is an empty array but I expect some data. I use Curl to the same url(copy paste from the logs) and I get some data back so probably its my app. But when I change the url, and try to log the response i do get a response back which indicates my app is fine. Now I don't know what to do.

My server is a Rails application. Here is the code:

```
  def search
  @query = params[:user]
  q="%#{@query}%"
  users = []

  @users = User.where("username like ?", q)
  for user in @users
    if (user.avatar)
      users << {username: user.username, avatar: user.avatar.image.thumbnail_dp}
    else
      users << {username: user.username, avatar: ""}
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => users.to_json }
  end
end
```

Here is my objective-c code

```
-(void)getFriends:(NSString *)query{

  Keychain *keychain = [[Keychain alloc]init];
  NSString *authToken = [keychain getAuthToken];
  NSString *url = @"http://url.json";
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?user=%@", url, query ];
  NSURL *main_url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  NSLog(@"url = %@", main_url);
  self.remote_response = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
  [request setURL: main_url];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
  [request setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-AUTH-TOKEN"];
  NSLog(@"request ===%@", request);
  self.remote_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  [self.remote_connection start];
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}
```

Here are the delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [self.remote_response setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"DID RECEIVE RESPONSE");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                               message:(@"Could not get friends with error %@", error)
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil , nil];
   [alert show];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d {
    [self.remote_response appendData:d];
    NSLog(@"Did receive data");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSError *error;
    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.remote_response
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [responseText dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseText);
    NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    if([responseDictionary count]>0){
         NSLog(@"Response::::%@", responseDictionary);

    }
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

Here is the NSURLResponse log I get

```
DID RECEIVE RESPONSE
Did receive data
Response ==> []
```

Edit:::
Found something. The params are not being set I have no idea why coz when I NSLog it, I see the params.

Here is the log if i Curl it

```
2013-09-05T07:30:58.222613+00:00 app[web.1]:Started GET "/search.json?user=heeman" for 58.137.173.76 at 2013-09-05 07:30:58 +0000
2013-09-05T07:30:58.428178+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#search as JSON
2013-09-05T07:30:58.428178+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"user"=>"heeman"}
2013-09-05T07:30:58.428178+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 200ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)
```

and here is the log through my ios client

```
2013-09-05T07:35:35.766319+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/search.json?user=heeman" for      58.137.173.76 at 2013-09-05 07:35:35 +0000
2013-09-05T07:35:35.778962+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/search.json?user=heeman host="host" fwd="58.137.173.76" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=51ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-09-05T07:35:35.773667+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#search as JSON
2013-09-05T07:35:35.773667+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"user"=>{}}
2013-09-05T07:35:35.773667+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

If you see in the logs, the url does show the params `method=GET path=/search.json?user=heeman` but then `Parameters: {"user"=>{}}`

Comment: Server log? Content of NSURLResponse?

Comment: Added the log and found something weird

Comment: Show the curl command. Why are you setting 'Content-type'?

Comment: `curl http://url/search.json?user=heeman` and I have no idea why, Let me try without the `Content-type`

Comment: yup, works without the `Content-type` although would you mind explaining it to me why me setting the content type got me an error?

Comment: Also if you put it as an answer I would be able to accept it

Comment: The reason why you see this error is as follows: Rails will merge query parameters and the body of the request into the params hash. From your query you got a {"user"=>"heeman"} and from your body content (since Content-Type has been specified you got {<model> => <request body>}, which is {"user"=> {}}. Now, I guess, the hash from the request will be added *after* the hash from the query string. Thus, adding the {"user"=>{}} hash from the request body into the merged hash will override your first entry - and the resulting hash becomes {"user"=>{}}    :) It's implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Content-type` setting on the request. You aren't including any data body, just the parameters, because this is a GET, not a PUT or POST. GET requests should not to include `Content-type` (they should only include `Accept`) though this isn't a hard requirement and the affect it will have depends on the server that is processing the request.